# Why the mail content sent are the raw html codes?

Tags: php, html, email, encoding

**Mail content:**

```
<html><head></head><body><p> Message : 鏽嫌╒杜米土 杯屎</p>Share Link : <a href = "http://203.80.1.28/FlippingBook/development/flipV5.html?page=70"> Press here to enter </a><br><img src ='http://203.80.1.28/FlippingBook/development/demo/medium/Web081112_P070_medium.jpg' /></body></html>
```

**PHP:**

```
if (isset($_POST["data"])){
    $info = explode("&", $_POST["data"]);
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n';
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset = \"UTF-8\";\n";
    $headers = "From: =?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode(substr($info[0],strpos($info[0],'=')+1, strlen($info[0]))) . "?=";
    $to = substr($info[1],strpos($info[1],'=')+1, strlen($info[1]));
    $subject = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode('日報分享') . "?=";
    $message = trim(substr($info[2],strpos($info[2],'=')+1, strlen($info[2])));
    $message = '<html><head></head><body><p> Message : '.$message;
    $url = substr($info[3],strpos($info[3],'=')+1, strlen($info[3]));
    $message = $message. '</p>Share Link : <a href = "'.$url.'"> Press here to enter </a>'; 

    if (isset($info[4])){
    $firstImg = substr($info[4],strpos($info[4],'=')+1, strlen($info[4]));
    $message = $message."<br><img src ='".$firstImg."' />";
    }

    if (isset($info[5])){
    $secondImg = substr($info[5],strpos($info[5],'=')+1, strlen($info[5]));
    $message = $message."<br><img src ='".$secondImg."' />";
    }
    $message = $message.'</body></html>';

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    die ('Mail sent');
    else
    die ('Fail');
}else{
    die ('Fail');
}
```

I am writing a simple program to send email. However, my mail content is not english based so I used utf-8 to encode.

When I changed the encode method, it can not send the processed html code, instead the mail content is the raw html code shown above, how to fix this problem?

Comment: Can we see an example of `$_POST["data"]` ?

Comment: $_POST["data"]='name=abc&email=abc@email.com&message=abcdefg&link=http://sample.com

Comment: Can we have a `var_dump($message)` before sending the email? To see what is inside this variable before checking the mail.

Comment: string(184) "
Message : 屠杳屎屠朽門杳

Share Link : Press here to enter 

" Mail sent

Comment: why the mail function in php format html code as plain text ?

Comment: it seems the define encode type statement is error, i fixed it , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using PEAR lib is not a problem than you can look for Pear Mail-Mime lib to send mail or HTML contents. More details you can get from here - http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php

Comment: unfortunely I don't have authority to do that, can it get done using mailto?

Comment: You can install PEAR packages locally, without needing root access on the machine.  Most are even BSD-licensed, so you can bundle them right in with your code.